# How to create a function that returns color between 2 colors in 2d color picker?

Tags: c++, math, colors

I want to create a hp bar,when hp is full (scale=1), the rgb is 100,200,255, (like bright green) and when hp is 0 (scale=0), the rgb is 100,50,0 (dark red):

```
void getHPBarColor(int startR,int startG,int startB,int endR,int endG,int endB,float scale);
```

which getHPBarColor(100,200,255,100,50,0,0.5) (half hp) will return something like yellow, which the yellow is the color between start color and end color in color picker.

Comment: You might want to edit your post and add a programming language tag, or nobody will find or read this question.

Comment: I think you are trying to do this in strange way. I suggest you two others solutions: 1. Fill hp bar with gradient (how to create on, you can google for it) and show only part of this rect. 2. Just pick three, four colors and set the color of rect. (e.g green if more then 50%, yellow if less then 50%, red if less then 15%, dark red if less then 5%). Gradient e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521493/creating-a-linear-gradient-in-2d-array

Comment: Paolo M, why you asking about framework? He ask about mathematical question about colors arithmetic and this is free of framework dependencies. He ask how to get answer for: Color A and Color B to get (Color A + Color B)/2 but in RGB space.

Comment: If you are looking at a color picker, then it's probably not right to do the colour "average" in RGB, but using a HSV variant. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your `Color` class. I have assumed you have a simple `Color` class that takes 3 ints (red green blue respectively). This also assumes you can pass your HP as a percent (which makes sense, since this function won't necessarily know how much 50hp is since max HP may be dependent on monster etc.)

```
struct Color
{
    int red;
    int green;
    int blue;

    Color(int r, int g, int b) : red(r), green(g), blue(b) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& oss, const Color& clr)
    {
        oss << clr.red << ", " << clr.green << ", " << clr.blue << endl;
        return oss;
    }
};

Color GetHPColor(double dPercent) { return Color(255-(255*dPercent), 0 + 255*dPercent, 0); }

int main() {
    cout << GetHPColor(0.0); // 255, 0, 0 at 0% hp
    cout << GetHPColor(0.5); // 127, 127, 0 at 50% hp
    cout << GetHPColor(1.0); // 0, 255, 0 at 100% hp
    return 0;
}
```

The colors you choose can be different. This was to give you the general gist of how you could do it.

Comment: exactly what i was thinkin, the only thing missing is, that pure red should never be visible (no life, no hp bar) so you might need to calculate a offset to get a neat gradient